# Failed to deploy the app. Error: Violation in UpdateServiceRequest.service.template.containers[0].volume_mounts[0].mount_path: must be a valid path

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcloud, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-code

I'm using `Visual Studio Code` with `Google Cloud Code` extension. When I try to use `Deploy to Cloud Run` with `Cloud SQL connections` field, I get this error:

> Failed to deploy the app. Error: Violation in UpdateServiceRequest.service.template.containers[0].volume_mounts[0].mount_path: must be a valid unix absolute path.

If I delete the Cloud SQL connection entry (PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID), the deploy works, but the connection fails:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

Is there a way to make the deploy work via UI? Via command line there are no errors.

Comment: Is there a specific code sample or tutorial you are trying to deploy? It is hard to debug without knowing your application code.

Comment: It looks like this might be a regression in Google Cloud Code as of 1.21.6, we're taking a look to confirm and if there is any mitigation you can use. You can also download the 1.21.5 extension to unblock yourself in the meantime https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.cloudcode 
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in the Google Cloud Code extension that has been fixed in version 1.21.8. If you reload the extension and rerun the Cloud Run deployment, you should no longer see this error.